# PHP 5.2 installation with GD on CentOS 6

Tags: php5, centos6.2, php5-gd

I am trying to install PHP 5.2.17 on CentOS 6.2. I have downloaded RPMs from http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/6/i386/RPMs/

Problem is that the PHP RPM seems to have GD disabled by default. Hence in spite installing php-gd RPM, GD is disabled.

Is there any way that I can enable GD. Atomicorp seems to be the only website that has PHP 5.2.17 RPMs.

I am not an advanced user to be able to compile PHP.

I would appreciate help on this.

Comment: Did you enable the gd-extension after installing the GD RPM? In the `php.ini` file you need something like this

    extension=gd.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in a comment by *pkhamre* you may just need to edit php.ini and enable the gd extension. *[change a line from `;extension=gd.so` to `extension=gd.so` in `php.ini` or if that line doesn't exist add it to your `php.ini`]*

Alternatively, if you are not looking for a specific version of PHP5, you can use a package manager. They are on most linux distro's and vary slightly from distro to distro but will take care of most of the issues involved with installing and keeping software up-to-date (**important**!).

On CentOS you should be able to `yum install php-gd` or similar.

Comment: Tried adding the line `extension=gd.so` to the `php.ini` file. It still wouldn't work.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say about what you are running? (Create an php page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and load up the page) Have you tried using `yum` ?

Comment: This is on a local server. So cannot put up a direct link. Although I have copied source and put it up on one of my sites for you to view. URL is http://www.security-list.com/notused/phpinfo.html. Yum always updates PHP to 5.3 which I want to avoid. Hence am not using yum. Thanks

Comment: Run `updatedb && locate gd.so` from a root shell and show me what it says please. It may be that `gd.so` is in the wrong place (since the RPMs are packaged from different authors). According to `extension_dir` in your phpinfo `gd.so` should be in `/usr/lib/php/modules`. Might I ask why you don't want to run php 5.3?

Comment: `gd.so` is located in `/usr/lib/php/modules/gd.so`. Some portions of the websites running on the web server are not compatible with PHP 5.3.

Comment: `gd.so` should be loading in that case. I believe the reason it isn't loading the `gd.so` shared library is because php was explicitly compiled `--without-gd`.

Comment: Is there a work around? I am not comfortable compiling PHP.

Comment: In a word, no. You either upgrade to 5.3 and have the 'easy' `yum install php-gd` option  or you compile from source and get exactly what you want. If you are familiar with using the shell/terminal/command-line and editing text files (which you seem to be), you should be fine compiling yourself. There are plenty of guides out there that will walk you through it (__Hint__: *Look for ones specific to CentOS 6*)